# bootstrap contact form send a blank email

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, email, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried unsuccessfully to fix the problem, I used a bootstrap contact form (template) send a blank email.

I searched on developers forum and this website as well, I tried some manipulation but it persists.

it maybe a question of (dot) missing ; but I'm not a PHP expert, I just know some basics...

HTML

```html
              <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required"></input>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required"></input>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required"></input>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button></input>
                </div>
              </form>
```

My sendemail.php

```html
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to     ='index@indexmarkets.biz';

$headers = [ // or array( for older PHP versions. 
 "MIME-Version: 1.0",
 "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1",
 "From: $name <$from>",
 "Reply-To: <$from>",
 "Subject: $subject",
 "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()
];

mail($to, $subject, $message, join('\r\n', $headers));

die;
```

JS

```js
// Contact form
 var form = $('#main-contact-form');
 form.submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
   data: {
                           name: $('input[name]').val(),
                           email: $('input[email]').val(),
                           subject: $('input[subject]').val(),
                           message: $('input[message]').val()
                              },
                        beforeSend: function(){
    form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
                        form.submit(function () {
                        $this = $(this);
                        $.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        },'json');
                        return false;
                        });
   }
  }).done(function(data){
   form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
  });
 });
```

Comment: Have a second look at your javascript. There are two different ajax calls combined into one. Clean it up, and your code might work. Start by removing the whole `beforeSend` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors for inputs are wrong.
Use

```js
data: {
  name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
  email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
  subject: $('input[name=subject]').val(),
  message: $('textarea[name=message]').val()
}
```

And as mentioned in comment, you are making another POST in `beforeSend` callback.

#### Update

While there's a lot that can be done, here's an example based on your own.

```js
(function ($) {
    var messages = {
        'progress': '<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending email...</p>',
        'success': '<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will contact you as early as possible.</p>',
        'error': '<p class="text-danger">Something went wrong.</p>'
    };
    var $form = $('form#main-contact-form');
    var formStatus = $('<div class="form_status"/>');
    $form.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                formStatus.html(messages.progress).fadeIn().prependTo($form);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success === true) {
                    formStatus.html(messages.success);
                } else {
                    formStatus.html(messages.error);
                }
                formStatus.fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            },
            error: function () {
                formStatus.html(messages.error).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            }
        });
    })
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<?php
$to = 'index@indexmarkets.biz';
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
$from = !empty($_POST['email']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) : $to;
$subject = !empty($_POST['subject']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['subject']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
$message = !empty($_POST['message']) ? filter_var(trim($_POST['message']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';

$body = "Name: {$name}\r\nEmail: {$from}\r\nMessage: {$message}";

$body = wordwrap($body, 70, "\r\n");

$headers = [
    'MIME-Version: 1.0',
    'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
    "From: $name <$from>",
    "Reply-To: <$from>",
    "Subject: $subject",
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion()
];

$success = @mail($to, $subject, $body, implode('\r\n', $headers));

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die(json_encode(['success' => $success]));
}

echo $success ? 'Sent Successfully.' : 'An error occurred';
```

Comment: kiko_software // Tushar Sharma thank you very much for your precious help, it works i receive the email from the form, but i receive the message and the subject only, how can i add the email adress of the sender ??

i dont master the JS.

Comment: @TiticheBoualem Please see the updated answer. I've also made minor corrections to HTML.

Comment: Tushar sharma
i thank you very very much for your time ; i tried to understand the changes before, it's more important to learn than to fix a problem ; you have optimized the code,... thank you, i updated my code and clean the history and cookies, ... but i had the same result, i receive the message and the subjet without name and email adress of the sender (from the form) !! is there another solution to include the adress email at least in the body of the email ?

Comment: @TiticheBoualem: I see. You're trying to get all the form details in mail body as well. You can do that by modifying `$message` before `wordwrap`. Let me update the example.

Comment: Tushar Sharma you helped me for free when i dont get support from the person i pay, your code work correctly and perfeclty too, in the comming month (havent visibility of an exact date) i will start an other business in Dubai, i need a person like you, rapid and efficacious, please send my your resume to class it on the top of my data base to amine@indexmarkets.biz if interessed.   Tushar Sharma thank you very much once again.